# Why does this declaration compile?

Tags: c

Why doesn't the following line of code produce an error?

```
double x = 4.2, y;
```

Also, x seems to be assigned to 4.2, and not the value of y (which seems to be 1e-39, or very close to 0).

Comment: It's declaring both `x` *and* `y`.

Comment: Why it should not compile?

Comment: Why isn't it being read as double x = 4.2; double x = y;?

Comment: If you want the behavior of the comma operator, do `double x = (4.2, y)`.

Comment: If you leave out the initialization, it's just like double x,y;

Comment: That is not an assignment statement, they are declarations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does the same as:

```
double x = 4.2;
double y;
```

The "y" variable contains some junk value (since its value is unspecified) until you give it a value.  It acts this way because the comma operator has lower precedence than assignment in C/C++.

Comment: Its value is just "unspecified" in the jargon of the C standard.

Comment: Fixed.  Compilers often set them to 0 (especially in debug mode) but this cannot be relied upon.

Comment: `y` doesn't "point at" some junk value; it *has* some junk value.

Comment: It should be noted that the phrasing of the question suggests the OP thought the `,` the declaration would be the comma operator. A good answer should explain that commas in a declaration are part of a list of things being declared, and that comma operators in expressions are different.

Comment: `y` will be initialized to `0.0` if the declaration is at file scope, outside any function. If it's at block scope, `y` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 8):

It's a declaration of two `double` objects, one named `x`, which is initialized to `4.2`, and one named `y`, which is not initialized.

It's more clearly written as:

```
double x = 4.2;
double y;
```

If it appears at file scope, `y` is implicitly initialized to `0.0`; otherwise its value will be garbage.

If you wanted an *assignment*, you'd have to drop the `double` keyword, for example:

```
x = 4.2;
```

If you wrote:

```
 x = 4.2, y;
```

then the `,` would be a comma operator, and since comma has lower precedence that `=`, it would be equivalent to:

```
(x = 4.2), y;
```

or:

```
x = 4.2;
y;
```

The reference to `y` is useless in that case.

Answer (score 3):

It is a declaration with an initial value assigned to `x` and no initial value for `y` (the value for `y` will be unspecified and depends upon the compiler).

These are all legal syntax:

```
double x, y;
double x = 4.2;
double x = 4.2, y;
```

I personally prefer to separate my declarations, e.g.:

```
double x = 4.2;
double y;
```

I find it more understandable and it is easier to modify should one of the types change or require additional commenting.

Comment: In C, a declaration is not a statement.

Comment: A declaration _may_ be a statement, as in a definition (which this is) which is also an implied declaration.

Comment: Nope. In C++, declarations are a subset of statements. In C, they're not. See section 6.8 of the ISO C standard; a *statement* can be any of *labeled-statement*, *compound-statement*, *expression-statement*, *selection-statement*, *iteration-statement*, or *jump-statement*. None of those can be a declaration.

Comment: So are you saying that the perfectly legal C statement `double x = 4.2;` is not a statement or is not a declaration?

Comment: I'm saying the perfectly legal C *declaration* `double x = 4.2;` is not a *statement*. I cited the definition of the word "statement" from the ISO C standard. If you think it's a statement, which of the six possible alternatives does it satisfy? What do *you* think the word "statement" means, and how do you reconcile your definition of the term with the unambiguous definition given in the standard?

Comment: I do not accept your assertion that an assignment is not a statement, and since this definition is both a declaration and an assignment it is therefore a statement.  Not having a copy of the C standard in front of me, I cannot verify that an assignment is not a statement, and what it is if not that.

Comment: I made no such assertion, but an assignment is an expression. Adding a semicolon to an expression makes it a statement, specifically an *expression-statement*. But `double x = 4.2;` does not contain an assignment. It contains an *initializer*, which is semantically similar to an assignment but syntactically distinct. Statements and declarations are entirely disjoint syntactic categories. The latest draft of the C standard is [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

`,` isn't comma operator here. It is a separator separating declarations of x (which is assigned to 4.2) and y.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring 2 variables of type `double`, you are only **assigning** a value to `x` though. `y` remains uninitialised and could contain any value. It is valid syntax to declare multiple variables of the same type with names separated by a `,`;

Answer (score 1):

Declaration assignment allows you to declare multiple variables in one line:

```
string s1;
string s2;
string s3 = "test";
```

is the same as:

```
string s1, s2, s3 = "test"
```

Comment: There is no predefined type `string` in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
double x = 4.2, y;
```

declares `x` variable of type double and initializes it with the value 4.2, and declares another variable called `y`. Note: why does NOT currently hold a value.
You statement could also be written as

```
double y, x = 4.2;
```